# The hover effect is obscure by the right div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time styling the hover in this exercise.
The effect isn't showing on the right side of the item card.
My first thought was to push the item further with padding and that didn't work at all.
So I tried adding margin and it just ruins the design I already made.

I would love it if you can help fix this issue. I'm stuck.

```css
.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.logo-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: arial;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.hvr-glow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
  transition-property: box-shadow;
}

.hvr-glow:hover,
.hvr-glow:focus,
.hvr-glow:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Mình nói gì khi nói Hạnh phúc</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(4)</span>
          <div>59.900 đ</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book2.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Thay đổi cuộc sống với nhân số học</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(1252)</span>
          <div>223.000 đ</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card ">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book3.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Sức mạnh của ngôn từ</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(445)</span>
          <p>79.900 đ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card ">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book4.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Tô Bình Yên Vẽ Hạnh Phúc</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(1234)</span>
          <p>53.700 đ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvsbW.png)

Comment: let me check it once.

Comment: The problem was actually z-index issue, please wait i will post the answer

Comment: add container-fluid before row if you used bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set box-shadow for col-*, refer to the code below:

```css
.col-sm-3 {
  padding: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

.col-sm-3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
}

.logo-image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: arial;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

.hvr-glow {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
  transition-property: box-shadow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Mình nói gì khi nói Hạnh phúc</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(4)</span>
          <div>59.900 đ</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book2.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Thay đổi cuộc sống với nhân số học</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(1252)</span>
          <div>223.000 đ</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card ">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book3.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Sức mạnh của ngôn từ</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(445)</span>
          <p>79.900 đ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
        <div class="card ">
          <img src="~/Content/Image/book4.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <p class="idname">Tô Bình Yên Vẽ Hạnh Phúc</p>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
          <span class="smallfont">(1234)</span>
          <p>53.700 đ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much. But I wonder if the straight up css on col-sm-3 will cause problem when I try to add responsive for mobile.

Comment: @DuongQuangChien you should add new class to `col-*` and set css for it. Do not custom default class of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the `z-index` value is lesser than the adjacent item. you can simply solve it by adding `z-index:99` (or some other value) on the `.col-sm-3:hover` event.

Please see the code below:

```css
.logo-image {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.logo-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
    
.card {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 220px;
    height:300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    background-color: white;
}

.hvr-glow {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow;
    transition-property: box-shadow;
}
.hvr-glow:hover, .hvr-glow:focus, .hvr-glow:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.col-sm-3:hover{
    z-index: 999 !important; /*this part will solve the issue.*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
            <div class="logo-image">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="idname">Mình nói gì khi nói Hạnh phúc</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
                    <span class="smallfont">(4)</span>
                    <div>59.900 đ</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
            <div class="logo-image">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="idname">Thay đổi cuộc sống với nhân số học</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
                    <span class="smallfont">(1252)</span>
                    <div>223.000 đ</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
            <div class="logo-image">
                <div class="card ">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="idname">Sức mạnh của ngôn từ</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
                    <span class="smallfont">(445)</span>
                    <p>79.900 đ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a target="_blank" class="hvr-glow" href="/">
            <div class="logo-image">
                <div class="card ">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width:100%">
                    <p class="idname">Tô Bình Yên Vẽ Hạnh Phúc</p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star gold"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty gold"></span>
                    <span class="smallfont">(1234)</span>
                    <p>53.700 đ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please resize the window to see the results, and if this solved your problem plz mark the answer as solved.Thank you

Comment: Let me try it. But thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: plz mark the answer as solved if this fixes your issue, or if there is any doubt feel free to ask